# wcf двусторонее соединение

Tags: .net, wcf

разрабатываю приложение для мониторинга. хотелось бы реализовать отправку сообщений от сервера клиентам без запроса. клиенты работают в основном за NAT`ом. Подойдет ли для этого дуплексный контракт? служба работает по net.tcp

Comment: вполне подойдёт, соединение-то устанавливают клиенты, даже если из под ната - это будет два разных соединения

Comment: вот только начал ковыряться в wcf и не таки не понимаю следующий момент: когда клиент устанавливает TCP-коннект с сервером - по этому каналу потом сервер и посылает мессадж в случае дуплексного соединения?

Comment: Клиент устанавливает соединение с сервером предоставляя серверной службе канал для обратной связи, по нему, собственно, уже и осуществляется обратная связь и серверу без разницы за натом клиент или нет - сообщение получит клиент, канал предоставивший

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на первый вопрос - да, вы все поняли правильно.

Ответ на вопрос из комментария: когда сервер посылает сообщение клиенту - он это делает по тому каналу, по которому вы ему сказали его послать. Чтобы запомнить канал к клиенту - вызовите `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel` - и сохраните куда-нибудь результат. При посылке сообщения через `CallbackChannel` оно пойдет по тому соединению, которое устанавливал клиент.

Если же вы просто *отвечаете* на клиентский запрос - то никакого дуплексного контракта не требуется. Ответ сервера всегда пойдет по тому каналу, по которому пришел запрос.